# How to configure a Java EE environnement on vs code?

Tags: java, configuration

I'm new to Java and encounter difficulties to configure a simple environnement for a Java Web project.
Java is installed, Maven, and a local tomcat server.

[image]

[image]

I just want to display my application on a web browser. I have tried multiple extensions (Community Server Connectors, etc.) but none are correctly working.

Right now I have a really basic app:
[image]

I just want to print this 'hello world' in a browser and have an hotreload possibility.

What would you recommand?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: I didn’t add that comment to be mean? I added it so you hopefully ask question better in the future. Glad you solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community connector extension was not correctly working because the server was placed in a location where admin right were required, cause it to malfunction.